# Issue in accessing a structure inside a union in C++

Tags: c++

```
   union hello
   {
      struct hi
      {
         uint8_t trees;
         uint8_t plants[6];
      };
      uint8_t forest[1 + 6];
   };

   struct world
   {
      hello a;
   };

typedef std::vector<world> universe;
universe alpha;
```

if I want to access the structure hi inside hello, then I am doing something like , assuming accessing the 1st vector element

```
alpha.at(1).a.hi.trees = 1; // error in accessing "hi" , why can't I access hi like this?
```

ERROR: type name is not allowed

Comment: Index of `std::vector` starts from 0. Is `alpha.at(1)` really the "1st vector element" that you want to access?

Comment: It looks like your intention will be to use `forest` and `hi` interchangeably. If you expect to be able to, for example use `forest[0]` to access `trees` then this is not allowed by the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `struct` is not a field of union in your version; it's just nested type name. change it to this:

```
   union hello
   {
      struct
      {
         uint8_t trees;
         uint8_t plants[6];
      } hi;/*<< put the field name here*/
      uint8_t forest[1 + 6];
   };
```

Comment: Yes this works but in C++ don't we put struct name beside struct and not after the struct?

Comment: @galaxy2096 Both are equally acceptable in both C and C++.

Comment: Unrelated: consider replacing `uint8_t forest[1 + 6];` with `uint8_t forest[sizeof(hi)];`. Offers defense against someone increasing `uint8_t plants[6];` to `uint8_t plants[8];` and forgetting they also need to change `1 + 6` to `1 + 8`.

Comment: @galaxy2096 I just did not intend to confuse anyone with the idea of anonymous structs. A named field is easier to do with.